# How to use Twitter username search with At.js in Meteor?

Tags: json, twitter, meteor

I'm wanting to use [At.js](https://atmospherejs.com/risul/autocomplete) in a Meteor project with auto-suggestion of Twitter usernames.

Any tips on how to use Twitter usernames as the data source? And to have it adjust the auto-suggestions as you type?

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting your Collection array as your data:

```
$('#search-field').atwho({
    at: "@",
    data: TwitterNames.find({}).fetch()
});
```

But looking at the original purpose of the library, maybe `at.js` is not the best choice for you; there are other autocomplete packages. I've tested this one once and worked great: http://typeahead.meteor.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'd had a look at http://typeahead.meteor.com/ but had dismissed it. On second thoughts, I think you're right, it will be a better fit for my needs.